# how to make bordered image in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I tried it following [Saving UIImage with rounded corners and border with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930584/saving-uiimage-with-rounded-corners-and-border-with-swift).

But border overlaps on the image.
[image]

I need clean bordered image.

How can I do for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my latest code.

```
func addEdgeAction(image: UIImage) -> UIImage{
        let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: image)

        let bgview: UIView = UIView()
        bgview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.frame.size.width + 200, height: imageView.frame.size.height + 200)
        var layer: CALayer = CALayer()
        layer = bgview.layer
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(8)
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 100

        let imageView1: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView1.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: imageView.frame.size.width, height: imageView.frame.size.height)
        bgview.addSubview(imageView1)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bgview.layer.bounds.size)
        layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        //secImg.image = roundedImage

        return roundedImage!
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
or 
imageView.contentMode = .center

You can also do this via storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach is to make sure that the imageView that contains the picture is completely proportional to the picture that you are enclosing so there are no gaps at any of the edges. Then the layer.borderColor and layer.borderWidth properties of the imageView work well.

Here is an example code:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var pippa: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let pippaPicture = UIImage(named: "user")
        let s = pippaPicture?.size
        let width = view.frame.width
        let height = (width/(s?.width)!) * (s?.height)!
        pippa = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:width, height:height))
        pippa.image = pippaPicture
        print(s!, width, height)
        pippa.layer.borderWidth = 5
        pippa.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        view.addSubview(pippa)
    }
}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you.
But I need a way to save clean bordered image or to get temporarily.
I am loading an image from Document folder or imageview